# Variable is null after setting value on FB.api function

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get the user locale and keep it on a variable.

```
function myFunction() {

  var userLocale;

  FB.api(
    "/{userID}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        userLocale = response.locale;
      }
    }
  );

}
```

When i set `userLocale` with the value that gives me the function, the `console.log(userLocale);` returns `undefined`.

`myFunction` is called after check if the user has access to my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably calling `console.log` before the callback function that sets the userLocale variable. The function you passed into `FB.api()` won't get called until Facebook responds. Your code to verify userLocale has a value should look like:

```
function myFunction() {

  var userLocale;

  FB.api(
    "/{userID}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        userLocale = response.locale;
        // Wait until I get an FB response before printing userLocale.
        console.log(userLocale);
        // Anything that requires userLocale goes here, not outside the FB.api() call.
      }
    }
  );

}
```

Comment: I see...All the values that gives me back the function i must use it inside it. I can't keep it in any other variable and use it on a second function.

Comment: make sure you understand what asynchronous javascript means

Comment: You can, but only call that code from within the callback function.

Comment: Ok, now I understand it. Thanks for the help.